# Run 2 parts through one cron job

Tags: java, servlets, cron

I am using quartz with cron to schedule 2 jobs . One runs at 12:00 and the other at 14:00 and it runs perfectly. Here's my code.

```
@Override
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
    JobDetail job1 = JobBuilder.newJob(FirstInvoiceGeneration.class)
            .withIdentity("FirstInvoiceGenerationJob", "group1").build();       
    Trigger trigger1 = TriggerBuilder
            .newTrigger()
            .withIdentity("FirstInvoiceGenerationTrigger", "group1")
            .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0 0 12 * * ?")).build();


    //Simple invoice generation to check which invoice to be generated today        
    JobDetail job2 = JobBuilder.newJob(TodayInvoiceGeneration.class)
            .withIdentity("TodayInvoiceGenerationJob", "group1").build();       
    Trigger trigger2 = TriggerBuilder
            .newTrigger()
            .withIdentity("TodayInvoiceGenerationTrigger", "group1")
            .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule(0 0 14 * * ?")).build(); 

    //Schedule it
    Scheduler scheduler;
        try {
            scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();               
            scheduler.start();
            scheduler.scheduleJob(job1, trigger1);
            scheduler.scheduleJob(job2, trigger2);

        } catch (SchedulerException e) {                    
            e.printStackTrace();            
        }   
}}
```

My two classes for running two jobs are :

```
    public class FirstInvoiceGeneration implements Job {            

                @Override
                public void execute(JobExecutionContext arg0)
                        throws JobExecutionException {
                    System.out.println("Listener running.");                        
                }
            }
```

my second class for second job is

```
    public class FirstInvoiceGeneration implements Job {            

                @Override
                public void execute(JobExecutionContext arg0)
                        throws JobExecutionException {      
                    System.out.println("Listener running.");                        
                }
            }
```

Now this runs perfectly , but what i want to do is to have 1 job that runs these two codes. Now i can use this cron expression --> "0 0 12,14 * * ?"
this will make the job run at 12pm , 2pm (my guess :p ). But i want to have only one class that execute one code when time is 12pm and other when time is 2pm. So can someone tell me how i can do it?

Comment: Why do you want to have those run in one cron line? (The only way I can see to make it work would be to have a function see what time it is and decide which class to call, which is horrible.) There's the normal way to do it (two cron lines), and there's the weird way to do it (one cron line); if you are going to ask how to implement the weird way, you should also say why you decided not to do it the normal way.

Comment: Could you pass in a command line argument to your application to say which piece of code?

Comment: Actually i have to run two big queries that will be running for 2-3 hours so sir said that maybe the two jobs might collide with each other . He said might not be thread safe . Is it? I am extremely new to quartz and all this.
So he said better to do it in one job to be safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Reference](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.1.7/org/quartz/TriggerBuilder.html). As you can see you can send data to a job by `usingJobData()` method to a job e.g. `("WORK","FIRST"),("WORK","SECOND")`.

In a single job class only check for the `WORK` key and accordingly do the operations you want to do. [JobExecutionContext](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.0/org/quartz/JobExecutionContext.html) you can retrieve the job data using `context.getJobDetails().getJobDataMap()`